# How to Kill specific x-window?

Tags: tty, xrandr

I run some WIndows games via Wine in new x-window on tt8. Here is what I use

```
Exec=xinit '/home/deckoff/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/HOMM3/drive_c/Program Files/GOG.com/Heroes of Might and Magic 3 Complete/Heroes3' -- :1 -ac -depth 16
```

This will invoke script, which reads

```
!# /bin/bash

# sleep 4 
xrandr -s 640x480
# xrandr -s 1024x768 
/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "ZumasRevenge.exe"
```

As you can see, I open a new x-windw and change resolution on the go. Sometimes, thoug, some of the games will freeze, and the x-window wont die, even if the game is closed. 
Usually, I can kill x with ctr-alt-bkspace, but this will work in tt7(default) only. In tty8the command will not work.

So, I want to know, is there a way to restrat or kil the x-window process taking place in tty8

Comment: I think you can kill x-window with Alt + sys-rq + K .

Comment: What is sys-rq button?

Comment: It is a keyboard key. See an example: http://imgur.com/iaoJC

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen+K - got it. This works. Anyway, I wrote a script, which can be used to kill Xorg at tty8. With some effort, it can be easily modified to kill anything at any tty :) 

Here it is<br />

#! /bin/bash

JOB=$(ps -A |  grep -w 'tty8' | grep -w 'Xorg')

JOBNUMBER=$(echo $JOB | awk 'BEGIN {  } ; {print $1}')
kill -9 $JOBNUMBER

Comment: Glad it works. So I will post as an answer if someone come here with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

<kbd>SysRq</kbd> is often the Print Screen key.

Comment: That killed all the windows and logged out of the window manager...thanks :P

Comment: ...as intended.

Comment: Doesn't work in 14.04. PrtScr is a Fn key on my laptop if that matters.

Comment: Yes it matters. You probably have to add the Fn key to the combination above.

Comment: Not working under 16.04

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
gksu xkill
```

you click on the window you want to close.

Also you could try with terminal
lets say banshee is stuck when you tried to listen an online radio station..

```
sudo ps -A|grep bans
>10304  bla bla bla
^ the result of the command
sudo kill 10304
```

you could try `sudo kill -s kill 10304`.

a more easy way

```
gksu gnome-system-monitor
```

this is all you need to know.

Comment: This will work most of the time, this is why I accept this answer. In this current case the app is working on its on in the new X window, so alt+f2 cannot bring command line :)

Comment: This one still works under 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a terminal:

```
echo "setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

The file `.xinitrc` in your home folder should be read every time X is started either via `startx`or `xinit`, and the option we just added should enable "zapping" the server.

For more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg

Comment: No, nothing happens, I added it, checked the file, the was correctly changed, restarted, but still this key combination will not work.
I think I can write a simple bash script to find xorg process running at tty8 and kill it. kill -9 some number will kill it